# KSOAP2 - connection refused

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I want to invoke a SOAP webservice with Android using KSOAP2. I managed to get the example in one of the tutorials working, but when trying to make it work on my own webservice, LogCat states "Connection refused". Currently the host address of the webservice is "http://localhost:9001/".
I can access it with SoapUI, but not via my Android App.

I can post the code if necessary, but what is the most likely reason for the error message?

And while I'm here: Is there a way to see what the message KSOAP is sending actually looks like? HttpTransport.requestDump seems only to be working if a connection could be established, which in my case  couldn't.

Comment: localhost, on your device (or emulator), is your device. The emulator sees your computer with address 10.0.2.2 (it should be that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that the address of your machine, as seen from the emulator, is `10.0.2.2`. More info here: [Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking).

About `HttpTransportSE.requestDump`: as you say, that will be filled only if there's actual communication (and if you set the `HttpTransportSE.debug` flag to `true`). If there's no communication, you have other problems than the content of it!

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, using 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost worked! Although there is however another problem with the webservice, I now at least know that I can establish a connection. Is there however another way to see the content of the sent xml-file, preferably without a connection to the webservice? (btw., I'd like to mark your answer useful, but unfortunately I'm not yet allowed to)

Comment: @deimos1988 I'm sorry, I can't help you with this. You could look into the envelope object to get an idea of the data, but no formatted xml. (If you want to accept the answer, you can click on the hollow tick mark next to the question to make it green, it will give reputation points to both of us, and let people know this is a working solution)

Comment: @deimos1988 in `HttpTransportSE.call()` there's a `createRequestData(envelope)` function that might be what you're looking, sadly I can't find where it's defined. https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-j2se/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/transport/HttpTransportSE.java